# Concatenate multiple rows in database - php

Tags: php

I have these data in my booked_tickets table:

1st Row: A1, A3, B2

2nd Row: C3, D2, A2

3rd Row: C1, A2, D1

When I tried to concatenate these data into one string, I get this:
A1, A3, B2C3, D2, A2C1, A2, D1

What I wanted is:
A1, A3, B2, C3, D2, A2, C1, A2, D1

How do I concatenate like that?

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultData) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
        $updateBookedSeats = $updateBookedSeats.$row['selected_bus_seats'];
        $updateTotalPassengers = $updateTotalPassengers + $row['number_of_passengers'];
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    $updateBookedSeats = explode(",", $updateBookedSeats);
    sort($updateBookedSeats);
    $updateBookedSeats = implode(",", $updateBookedSeats);
}
```

Ignore the `$updateTotalPassengers`, that works fine on its own.

Comment: This `$updateTotalPassengers = $updateTotalPassengers +` can be simplified to `$updateTotalPassengers +=` you then should put a `,` in there. You can use `rtrim` after the loop to remove the last one... or `$updateBookedSeats` is the same thing... and use `.=` for the operator.

Comment: I just managed to solve it similar like your solution. I concatenate a comma and then got rid of the last comma character by using a substr(). Thanks for the help!

Comment: `rtrim` will be safer than `substr` because it would only remove a trailing comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to update this line

`$updateBookedSeats = $updateBookedSeats.$row['selected_bus_seats'];`

With additional `,` at end like:

`$updateBookedSeats = $updateBookedSeats.$row['selected_bus_seats'].',';`

Comment: This works!. I'll then just use a substr() function to get rid of the last comma character. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To get rid of the last comma character you could use `rtrim($s,',')` instead of `substr()`.